# Error Context is read only en grails 2.4.3

Tags: grails

Estoy intentando usar GROBID (http://grobid.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) en una aplicación en grails. Probé el ejemplo básico que viene en la documentación en Java desde el Netbeans y funciona bien, pero en grails me da el error:

```
| Error 2016-03-13 16:37:59,899 [http-bio-8080-exec-4] ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - OperationNotSupportedException occurred when processing request: [GET] /GROB/grobid
Context is read only. Stacktrace follows:
Message: Context is read only
    Line | Method
->>  961 | checkWritable     in org.apache.naming.NamingContext
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    548 | createSubcontext  in     ''
|    574 | createSubcontext  in     ''
|    487 | createSubcontext  in org.apache.naming.SelectorContext
|    483 | createSubcontext  in javax.naming.InitialContext
|     37 | setInitialContext in org.grobid.core.mock.MockContext
|     76 | setInitialContext in     ''
|     24 | getText           in Grob.test
|      9 | index . . . . . . in grob.GrobidController
|    198 | doFilter          in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter
|     63 | doFilter . . . .  in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter
|   1145 | runWorker         in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . . . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run               in java.lang.Thread
```

Lo mejor es que si creo el .war de la aplicación y la despliego (ya sea desde el mimso grails o desde un servidor tomcat local) **todo funciona tal como lo espero**

Esta es la clase test.java:

```
import org.grobid.core.data.BiblioItem;
import org.grobid.core.engines.Engine;
import org.grobid.core.factory.GrobidFactory;
import org.grobid.core.mock.MockContext;
import org.grobid.core.utilities.GrobidProperties;

import java.io.File;

public class test {

    public String getText() throws Exception {

        String root = "/media/jose/Datos/DOCUMENTS/Datos/Gobid/GROBID_COMPILED";

        String pdfPath = root + File.separator + "doc" + File.separator + "GROBID.pdf";
        String pathGHome = root + File.separator + "grobid-home";
        String pathGProp = root + File.separator + "grobid-home" + File.separator + "config" + File.separator + "grobid.properties";
        String resp = "";

        MockContext.setInitialContext(pathGHome, pathGProp);
        GrobidProperties.getInstance();

        Engine engine = GrobidFactory.getInstance().createEngine();
        BiblioItem bi = new BiblioItem();

        resp = engine.processHeader(pdfPath, false, bi);

        MockContext.destroyInitialContext();

        return resp;

    }

}
```

y este el controlador donde la llamo GrobidController.groovy:

```
package grob
import Grob.test

class GrobidController {

    def index() {

        def g = new test()
        def resp = g.getText()

        [resp: resp]

    }

}
```

Alguien me puede decir que es lo que puede estar pasado.
Gracias de antemano.